# How to sample height map which is stored in the alpha channel of the normal map?

Tags: directx, directx-9, directx-10, heightmap

> error X3523: DX9-style intrinsics are disabled when not in dx9 compatibility mode

how to use the `tex2Dgrad()` function in dx10?

Answer (score 1):

You could turn on the back-compat mode (i.e. use `/Gec` switch with the `FXC.EXE` command-line or the `D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY` flag with the D3DCompile APIs).

Alternatively, instead of using the DirectX 9 style `tex2Dgrad()` intrinsic, use the 'Texture object' syntax that was introduced with Direct3D 10 / Shader Model 4:

```
Texture2D <float4> MyTex : t0;
Sampler MySampler : s0;

float4 value = MyTex.SampleGrad(MySampler, TexCoord, dx, dy);
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509700.aspx)

> Note that there is no reason to use the Direct3D 10.x API at all. You should be using Direct3D 11 which supports a [broader range of hardware](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels/), has clearer thread-safety syntax, supports additional features, and has a much better supported set of [utility libraries](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/). Direct3D 11 is available on all [supported platforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416644.aspx) that included Direct3D 10. See this [ppt](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/11/DirectX-11-Technology-Update.zip) from Gamefest 2010 for a detailed walkthrough of the differences.